# Use frontend attribute values when creating orders from admin

Tags: attributes, orders

When creating an order from admin that includes a configurable product, the option is displayed using the admin value of the attribute.

In my case, I use a different admin value and frontend value.

Does anyone know of a way to force the use of the frontend value?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, you need to override this method `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController::configureProductToAddAction()`.
You need to replace :

```
$helper->renderConfigureResult($this, $configureResult);
```

with

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($sessionQuote->getStore()->getId());
$helper->renderConfigureResult($this, $configureResult);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(0);
```

This is needed because in order to retrieve the option values, Magento uses the same blocks as it does in the frontend. At least this one `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable`. And somewhere in the process of retrieving  the options I'm sure it checks for the current website. Basically the code above just sets the current store to the one used for the order, renders the values and sets the current store back to `admin`.

Comment: Nice solution! just wondering, would store emulation not be cleaner in this situation? http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/emulate-store-in-magento/

Comment: Even if in this case won't make a difference, you are right. It's cleaner that way

Comment: Cheers Marius and Sander. Your answers were worth waiting for!